# PHP mkdir() Invalid Path

Tags: php, mkdir

I'm trying to save files on my server, and as a prerequisite, create directories that don't exist.

I am running a script, `dl.php`, at `/home/public_html/www3/scripts/dl.php`:

```
$request['savedir'] = '/home/public_html/www3/scripts/images/logs';
if( !is_dir($request['savedir']) )
    mkdir($request['savedir']);
```

And I get:

```
Warning: mkdir(): Invalid path in /home/public_html/www3/scripts/dl.php
```

The "images" does exist.

Comment: are you running the script via another php script called in a browser (basically by Apache) or on the server command line as root or another user?

Comment: I'm running the script directly at the moment, but in production it will be run by a a jQuery Ajax post call.

Comment: Wait , didn't read that completely. it's being called by the browser directly, sorry

Comment: I just forgot to type it here, it's there on the script, just checked.

Comment: I am assuming missing $ is just a typo since the error doesn't complain about it but I am more thinking about user privileges on the folders. Those must be "apache" group and user to be written by Apache (meaning when it works as web application via browser).

Comment: @Mat the images folder does exist. It shouldn't need to be recursive.

Comment: Did you check your "images" folder user and group and permissions? They are all ok?

Comment: @smozgur Just did, turns out in creation of the folder, it had wrong permissions. I changed them to 700, and it's working. Thanks! Please make this an answer.

Comment: Glad to hear it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check your "images" folder owner and permissions. It requires to be write enabled to be used with "apache" user/group when it is executed in browser. The error is actually about "permissions" since it is not visible to "apache" user.

Answer (score 18):

1. Open the `config.php` on `application/config` folder
2. Browse all the way down to the `$config['sess_save_path'] =  NULL;` line.
3. Change the `NULL` value to `BASEPATH.'sessions'`